# Rewrite a sql query for better optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, msbi

I have a table that has the following data

| id | orderid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |

An id can have multiple order ids. If an id has only a single row with orderid 0 then it indicates that the order is not placed yet. I have find all the ids for which orders are not placed yet.

Here's what I came up with

```
Select *
From (
    Select
      id,
      orderId,
      Count(id) Over (partition by id) 'cntId'
    From table
) a
Where a.cntId = 1
and a.Orderid = 0
```

Is there a better way to write this query? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does the table have a PK? What indexes does the table have? What's the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it like this

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*)=1
       and max(orderid)=0;
```

Comment: This answer likely cannot use any index due to the `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen An index on `(id, orderid)` would result in a `Stream Aggregate` with no `Sort`, so pretty efficient

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the aggregation approach, I prefer:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(orderid) = MAX(orderid) AND MIN(orderid) = 0;
```

This query should benefit from an index on `(id, groupid)`.

My answer doesn't select the `groupid` value, but we already know that this value would have to be zero for the entire result set.

Answer (score 0):

If you KNOW the sequential ordering of the / order IDs will always be 0, 1, 2, etc, and you have an index on (id, orderid), I would self-join for so it does not need to query for those IDs that may have 100+ orders

```
select
      yt.id
   from
      YourTable yt
         LEFT JOIN YourTable yt2
            on yt.id = yt2.id
           and yt2.orderid = 1
   where
          yt.orderid = 0
      AND yt2.id is null
```

So it will only ever care about an order ID = 0 or 1 and return only those where no orderID = 1 is found.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` would probably be even better